# How to detect hardware key taps?

Tags: flutter

I am at a point where I need to detect if any of the hardware buttons was presses when the flutter app is in foreground or when it is open.*

For example, when someone presses a volume or another button (even if it is the power off one) I want to perform some action in my app.

I know that when a flutter app is open and I am looking at the app logs and I tap any hardware button is tapped the lops related to that tap is printed in the logs.

Like when I press Vol down Key Down Tap Detected related logs are printed in logs.

How do can I perform a function when any of the above specified action is performed?

Answer (score 6):

New plugin called [Hardware Buttons](https://pub.dev/packages/hardware_buttons) was released just a few days ago.

It supports volume button events and power button events, which seems like fits your need.

Maybe have a go with this?

Comment: is there one for listening when a phone is unlocked (via prints, face, pin id) ?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter-moum/flutter_hardware_buttons see there, it's now "deprecated" it says

Answer (score 4):

You will need find the proper flutter packages to do so.

Any system level call needs to use the platform channel api

https://flutter.io/platform-channels/

Here is the repository

https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter/

Here is an example of a method channel.

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/device_info/lib/device_info.dart

Here is an example of a stream listener.

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/sensors

The stream listener wasn't really well documented when I tried to grab mic fragments.

Comment: is there one for listening when a phone is unlocked (via prints, face, pin id) ?

Comment: @Gel https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth Is this what you are looking for?