# Flutter - listening to hardware keys. Preventing from default behavior, android

Tags: android, flutter

I want to get this: listen to HW keys (ex. Volume key) but preventing it from default behavior (ex. I press Volume key > my app react to that > but sound volume should **not** change).
This is easy in Java android but I cant stop this event in FLutter.
This is demo code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' as serv;

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));



class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    serv.RawKeyboard.instance.addListener((serv.RawKeyEvent k){
      print(k);
    });
    return Scaffold(body: SafeArea(
      child: Text("TEST"),
    ),);
  }
}
```

But when I press volume button sound volume is also changed.
How to stop this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042168/detect-hardware-key-taps-flutter?newreg=0306be36515c4511a3957795273d2141

Comment: got any solution ???

Comment: I don't get volume key event at al by using RawKeyboard.instance.addListener...

Comment: @ChiragChopra Please check my answer :]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Shortcuts-class.html
There is a widget `Shortcuts` and `Actions` are consumer of Intent sends by hw keys.